# Generators in Python Query

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand Generators and have come across the following code:

```
def reverse(data):
    for index in range(len(data)-1, -1, -1):
        yield data[index]


for s in reverse([1,2,3]):
    print s
```

I understand that we start at index `2`, decrement by `1` and end at `-1`. What I don't get is the fact that the stopping point `-1` ,I thought, should refer to `"3"`, but it appears to refer to `"1"` here? :

```
3
2
1
```

Thanks

Comment: check the output of `range(len(data)-1, -1, -1)` before assuming anything about the stopping point (especially since the evidence point against your assumption)

Comment: `range` actually stops before the upper limit. Presumably it behaves this way to ensure `for i in range(3)` will iterate 3 times as most people would expect, with `i` taking on the values `[0, 1, 2]`. In your case, `range(2, -1, -1)` outputs `[2, 1, 0]`, which corresponds to the indices of the output you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Please see https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range to see how range works. I can see it may be initially confusing to read the documentation but hope my explanation below, for your case, helps.

Specifically these lines from the above doc answers your question:
**' The full form returns a list of plain integers `[start, start + step, start + 2 * step, ...]`. If step is positive, the last element is the largest `start + i * step` less than *stop*; if step is negative, the last element is the smallest `start + i * step` greater than *stop*'**

In your case `start=2`(len(data)-1)`, stop =-l and step=-1`. So the potential list of integers would be `[2, 2-1, 2-2*1, 2-3*1 ...]` which is `[2,1,0,-1 ...]`. However since your step is negative, i.e, -1, the last element would be smallest (`start + i*step`) greater than *stop*. In the potential list, the smallest item greater than stop, i.e greater than -1 is 0. So `range(len(data)-1, -1, -1)` returns `[2,1,0]`